# Syntax Error for the following code

Tags: syntax

I have the following code in mathematica

```
\[Alpha] = 3;
 f[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/\[Alpha])]; 
 F = Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals},Integrate[f[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]/Pi]; 
 Z= FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@Re[F], {t > 0, A > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}]
```

We can see that $Z$ is a function of $t$.

Now I want to perform the following operation

$$S(x)=\int_0^{\infty}te^{-tx}Z(t)dt$$

For which I write the code

```
S = Integrate[t*Exp[-t*x]*Z, {t, 0, \Infinity}]
```

But, I get some error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You know that `LaplaceTransform[]` and `InverseLaplaceTransform[]` are built-in, no?

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. Your integration statement has a slash in front of infinity.
2. Put the same `Assumption` about `A` in the final integral as you had in the integration that generated `F`.

Then you get an answer:

```
S = Assuming[{A > 0, A \[Element] Reals}, 
  Integrate[t*Exp[-t*x]*Z, {t, 0, Infinity}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, Now S is function of both t and x. I just want it as a function of x. Is it possible to find that?